# Class methods when overloading addition operator in Python

Tags: python, operator-overloading

In Python, I'm looking for the best way to deal with methods when you overload the addition operator.

In the example below, I'm trying to figure out what I should put in the **add** method in the Function class.

```
class Function(object):

    def calculate(self, x):
        raise NotImplementedError()

    def __add__(self, other):
        res = Function()
        res.calculate = lambda x: self.calculate(x) + other.calculate(x)
        return res

class Square(Function):

    def calculate(self, x):
        return x**2

class Cube(Function):

    def calculate(self, x):
        return x**3
```

In the example, if I wanted to compute 2^2 + 2^3, I'd do something like

```
f = Square() + Cube()
print f.calculate(2)
```

My way of doing this didn't seem obvious, so I'm guessing there's a better way.  Not sure if it helps, but in my real problem, I'm working with (statistical) kernels.  I'd have to handle multiple methods, and I'd also need to overload the multiplication operator.

Comment: Not really what you asked, but you might find [sympy](http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) interesting

Comment: It's been a while since the question was asked, so I'd like to give it a try. But I can't figure out why would you do it like this, and not have a class function with an attribute i.e. `code="x**2+y**2+x"` which you could `eval` in coordinates you need? Like this you would literally need to define every possible function you can think of and they don't really represent their canonical forms in this example (i.e. actual square function would be `a*x**2+b*x+c`. Could you describe a bit what exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

For a better way, Take a look at `numpy.poly1d()` which is implemented as a function instead of a class. Something like this might suit your needs:

```py
def poly(*coeffs):
    def _poly(x,coeffs=coeffs):
        return sum(c*x**i for i,c in enumerate(coeffs))
    return _poly
```

Then you can use it like this:

```py
fn = poly(4,5,6)
ret = fn(7)
assert(ret == 333)
```

In this example, I calculated:

```
4 + 5 * 7 + 6 * 7**2
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'm not really looking to add polynomials--I'm looking to add similarity measures and gradients from a few statistical kernels .  The polynomial thing was meant to be a simple example.

Comment: But the example should still be valid for what you want to do I think. Basically a function to create another function.